# How can I get 100% scaling in Inkscape to match reality on my screen?

Tags: 22.04, wayland, inkscape, dpi

When designing something in Inkscape I would like to get the size on screen to match reality when setting the scale to 100%. Currently I have to set it to 114%.

Is it possible to accomplish that? Do I have to reconfigure screen DPI somewhere?

The problem also applies to Libre office - there I am not able to set 114% scaling

Is it also possible to do such for different screens (Laptop screen and big external screen)?

I did not find any approach yet in Google for this.

In the display settings there is a "fractional scaling" feature, but this does not seem the right thing (and also does not allow arbitrary percentages).

Answer (score 1):

In preferences, there is a setting to set the ruler/zoom offset allowing you to make 100% on the screen the same are real life.

You may have to use 1.3 to get the zoom amount shown in the interface to be 100% though. This is just a ui bug though.

Comment: Thanks, is there a recommended system wide way to apply this also for other applications, like Libre Office?

Comment: No, this is an inkscape feature only. I don't believe any other programs support it.